# Place figure on full page between text, instead of at the end

Tags: floats

How can I get my tikz picture between the two lipsums? So the lipsums fill a full page, then my Markov maps fill a full page and the lipsums continue after them. I have three of these figures and they all only show up at the end of the chapter, which is annoying for reading the results explaining these Markov maps, as you need to scroll through many pages.

(Their normal size is 17 x 17, however this does not fit the question).

```
\usepackage{tikz}           
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}             
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\chapter{test}
\lipsum

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Cluster 1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily, ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix (A) [nodes in empty cells,
matrix of nodes,
nodes={draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, rotate=90, anchor=west, inner xsep=1mm}},
column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=30mm, text width=28mm, align=right}},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth
]
{   \&  AC  \&  CH  \&  DP  \&  HP  \&  IA  \&  LB  \&  LP  \&  NL  \&  SC  \&  show\_discount\_reminder    \&  show\_funnel\_campaign  \&  show\_recc  \&  show\_recp  \&  show\_upsell                            \\
AC  \& |[fill=black!    1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  11  ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  85  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1                           ]|\\
CH  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  38  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
DP  \& |[fill=black!    1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  12  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  66  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
HP  \& |[fill=black!    1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  57  ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  25  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
IA  \& |[fill=black!    3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  14  ]|\& |[fill=black!  13  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  16  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  33  ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
LB  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
LP  \& |[fill=black!    4   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  24  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
NL  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  14  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  21  ]|\& |[fill=black!  57  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
SC  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  55  ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17                          ]|\\
show\_discount  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  7   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  78  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
show\_funnel    \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  87  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
show\_recc  \& |[fill=black!    9   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  30  ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
show\_recp  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
show\_upsell    \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  82  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1                           ]|\\
show\_wijnatlas \& |[fill=black!    13  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  62  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  12  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
WV  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  33  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  45  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subcaptionbox{Cluster 2}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily, ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix (A) [nodes in empty cells,
matrix of nodes,
nodes={draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, rotate=90, anchor=west, inner xsep=1mm}},
%column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=43mm, text width=40mm, align=right}},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth
]
{       AC  \&  CH  \&  DP  \&  HP  \&  IA  \&  LB  \&  LP  \&  NL  \&  SC  \&  show\_discount\_reminder    \&  show\_funnel\_campaign  \&  show\_recc  \&  show\_recp  \&  show\_upsell                            \\
     |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  11  ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  85  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  38  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  12  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  66  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  57  ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  25  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  14  ]|\& |[fill=black!  13  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  16  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  33  ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  4   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  24  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  14  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  21  ]|\& |[fill=black!  57  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  55  ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17                          ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  7   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  78  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  87  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  9   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  30  ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  82  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  13  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  62  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  12  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  33  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  45  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subcaptionbox{Cluster 3}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily, ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix (A) [nodes in empty cells,
matrix of nodes,
nodes={draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
%row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, rotate=90, anchor=west, inner xsep=1mm}},
column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=30mm, text width=28mm, align=right}},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth
]
{ AC    \& |[fill=black!    1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  11  ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  85  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1                           ]|\\
CH  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  38  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
DP  \& |[fill=black!    1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  12  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  66  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
HP  \& |[fill=black!    1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  57  ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  25  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
IA  \& |[fill=black!    3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  14  ]|\& |[fill=black!  13  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  16  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  33  ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
LB  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
LP  \& |[fill=black!    4   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  24  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
NL  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  14  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  21  ]|\& |[fill=black!  57  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
SC  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  55  ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17                          ]|\\
show\_discount  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  7   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  78  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
show\_funnel    \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  87  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
show\_recc  \& |[fill=black!    9   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  30  ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
show\_recp  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
show\_upsell    \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  82  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1                           ]|\\
show\_wijnatlas \& |[fill=black!    13  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  62  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  12  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
WV  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  33  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  45  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
XT  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subcaptionbox{Cluster 4}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily, ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix (A) [nodes in empty cells,
matrix of nodes,
nodes={draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
%row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, rotate=90, anchor=west, inner xsep=1mm}},
%column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=43mm, text width=40mm, align=right}},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth
]
{        |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  11  ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  85  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  38  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  12  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  66  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  57  ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  25  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  14  ]|\& |[fill=black!  13  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  16  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  33  ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  4   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  24  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  14  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  21  ]|\& |[fill=black!  57  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  55  ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17                          ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  7   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  78  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  87  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  9   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  30  ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  82  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  13  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  62  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  12  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  33  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  45  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subcaptionbox{Cluster 5}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily, ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix (A) [nodes in empty cells,
matrix of nodes,
nodes={draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
%row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, rotate=90, anchor=west, inner xsep=1mm}},
column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none,minimum width=30mm, text width=28mm, align=right}},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth
]
{AC \& |[fill=black!    1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  11  ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  85  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1                           ]|\\
CH  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  38  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
DP  \& |[fill=black!    1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  12  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  66  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
HP  \& |[fill=black!    1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  57  ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  25  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
IA  \& |[fill=black!    3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  14  ]|\& |[fill=black!  13  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  16  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  33  ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
LB  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
LP  \& |[fill=black!    4   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  24  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
NL  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  14  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  21  ]|\& |[fill=black!  57  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
SC  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  55  ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17                          ]|\\
show\_discount  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  7   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  78  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
show\_funnel    \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  87  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
show\_recc  \& |[fill=black!    9   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  30  ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
show\_recp  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
show\_upsell    \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  82  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1                           ]|\\
show\_wijnatlas \& |[fill=black!    13  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  62  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  12  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
WV  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  33  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  45  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
XT  \& |[fill=black!    0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0                           ]|\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption[Markov maps for the 6-MMM]{Markov maps for the 6-MMM applied to Member data, showing the transition probabilities.}
\label{fig:TP_MMM}
\end{figure}


\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try with replacing `[h]` with `[!htbp]`?

Comment: The only reason to put anything in a `figure` is to allow tex to move it. If you do not want it to move do not use `figure`. Using `[h]` makes going to the end very likely as it means not top, not bottom, not on float page (as no `t`, `b` or `p`) so it gives very few places where the figure can be placed.

Comment: Your code does not compile as the `documentclass` and the `subcaption` package are missing at the beginning. After adding this, there still is a warning `LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 504.49994pt on input line 166.` because you put all your five `tikzpicture`s into one `figure` (results in an output only showing two and a half `tikzpicture`).